# about gravity option for marks in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using the Text widget in python / tkinter.

I want to use the left and right option for marks so that text inserted immediately before or immediately after already tagged text is in the same tag range.

In the code below, I don’t understand why inserted text does not appear in red.

```py
import tkinter as tk

main = tk.Tk()
tt = tk.Text(main, width=50, height=5, bg='lightgray')
tt.pack()

# some text
tt.insert('1.0', 'STRANGE!')

# inserting marks in text
tt.mark_set('redLeft', '1.2')
tt.mark_gravity('redLeft', 'left')
tt.mark_set('redRight', '1.6')
tt.mark_gravity('redRight', 'right')

# a tag for red text
tt.tag_add('red', 'redLeft', 'redRight')
tt.tag_configure('red', foreground='red')

# insertions after, in and before red text
tt.insert('1.6', 'should be red ?')
tt.insert('1.4', 'is red')
tt.insert('1.2', 'should be red ?')

main.mainloop()
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don’t understand why inserted text does not appear in red.

This is how the text widget is designed to work. The gravity of a mark does not affect the tags that are applied when inserting text. The gravity only defines what happens to the mark when text is inserted at the mark.

From the [canonical documentation on marks](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/text.htm#M71):

*"The gravity for a mark specifies what happens to the mark when text is inserted at the point of the mark. If a mark has left gravity, then the mark is treated as if it were attached to the character on its left, so the mark will remain to the left of any text inserted at the mark position. If the mark has right gravity, new text inserted at the mark position will appear to the left of the mark (so that the mark remains rightmost)."*

When you insert text, the text will only inherit tags if the tag is on the character *both* to the left and the right of the insertion point.

From the [canonical documentation on the insert method](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/text.htm#M131):

*"If there is a single chars argument and no tagList, then the new text will receive any tags that are present on both the character before and the character after the insertion point; if a tag is present on only one of these characters then it will not be applied to the new text.*"

Answer (score 1):

Now that you know the answer from dear Bryan Oakley, you can still achieve the desired effect. In the `insert` method, you can specify the desired tag by finding its name using `tag_names`. You just need to subtract one from the right index to get the desired tag.

```
import tkinter as tk

red_left = '1.2'
red_right = '1.6'

main = tk.Tk()
tt = tk.Text(main, width=50, height=5, bg='lightgray')
tt.pack()

# some text
tt.insert('1.0', 'STRANGE!')

# a tag for red text
tt.tag_add('red', red_left, red_right)
tt.tag_configure('red', foreground='red')

#insertions after, in and before red text
tt.insert(red_right, 'should be red ?', tt.tag_names(red_right +'-1c'))
tt.insert('1.4', 'is red')
tt.insert(red_left, 'should be red ?',tt.tag_names(red_left))

main.mainloop()
```